# Hiding a part of column and making it appear through mouseover using knockout

Tags: knockout.js

I have a table:

```
table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>

            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Description</th>


        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody data-bind="foreach: Curriculums">
        <tr>
            <td data-bind="text: ID"></td>

            <td>
                <div data-bind="event: { mouseover: toggle, mouseout: toggle }>
                    <span data-bind="text: curCode"></span>
                </div>
                <div data-bind="visible: selected">
                    <span data-bind="text: curDescription"></span>
                </div>
            </td>       

        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

this is my knockout js

```
var Vm =
{

    Curriculums: ko.observableArray([]),
    ID: ko.Observable(),

    curCode: ko.observable(),
    curDescription: ko.observable(),

    selected: ko.observable(false),

    toggle: function() {
       this.selected(!this.selected());   
    }
}
```

I am trying to load all of the records of curriculum table. I successfully retrieved it and displayed it without the mouse over/out bindings. The problem is when I implement the mouseover and mouseout bindings, the knockout throws an error:

```
Uncaught Error: Unable to parse bindings.
Message: ReferenceError: toggle is not defined;
Bindings value: event: { mouseover: toggle}
```

how can I make this work? I am hiding the curDescription span if the mouse is not hovering and make it reappear when the mouse hovers to the curCode span

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`toggle` should be prefixed with `$parent` as you are using it inside a [`foreach`](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/foreach-binding.html) binding. Otherwise knockout will look for the function inside each 
 item in `Curriculums` array.

```
<tbody data-bind="foreach: Curriculums">
    <tr>
        <td data-bind="text: ID"></td>

        <td>
            <div data-bind="event: { mouseover: $parent.toggle, mouseout: $parent.toggle }>
                <span data-bind="text: curCode"></span>
            </div>
            <div data-bind="visible: selected">
                <span data-bind="text: curDescription"></span>
            </div>
        </td>       

    </tr>
</tbody>
```

This still won't give you the expected result. `ID`, `curCode` `selected` and `curDescription` should be properties of items in `Curriculums` array. You don't need to have that in your `Vm`

```
var Vm = {
  Curriculums: ko.observableArray([{
    ID: 1,
    curCode: "CS101",
    curDescription: "Why C#?",
    selected: ko.observable(false) // this needs to be an observable
  }, {
    ID: 2,
    curCode: "CS102",
    curDescription: "Javascript 101",
    selected: ko.observable(false)
  }]),

  // "item" will have the current "Curriculum" element which triggered the event
  toggle: function(item) {
    item.selected(!item.selected());
  }
}
```

Here's a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/adigas/6gyp8vgn/) for you test. Go through the knockout documentation and play around with some fiddles to get a good understanding of ko bindings.

As mentioned in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46489844/3082296) on the other question, you can achieve this by pure `CSS`. But again, it's important you understand how binding works inside `foreach`.

Comment: I tried following your answer. it says "Uncaught TypeError: item.selected is not a function"
I already added that property in my curriculum

Comment: @NoobProgger Did you check the fiddle? You need to change your `Vm`.  `selected` should be an `observable` property of items in `Curriculums` array. `selected: ko.observable(false)`

Comment: yup, that fiddle sample is what i am trying to achieve. but when I implement it on my project, that's the error. i already declared selected: ko.observable(false)

Comment: @NoobProgger I'm not talking about the `selected` inside the `Vm`. That is redundant. How are you populating `Curriculums`? I'm assuming you are assigning it with plain js array. Each item in `Curriculums` should have a `selected: ko.observable(false)` property.

Comment: but how can I declare the selected as observable if I am retrieving the list of curriculum from the database?

Comment: @NoobProgger loop and add a `selected: ko.observable(false)` property to the array. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16105059/how-to-add-array-of-objects-into-observable-array-in-knockout

Comment: @NoobProgger something [like this](https://jsfiddle.net/adigas/6gyp8vgn/1/) or [this](https://jsfiddle.net/adigas/6gyp8vgn/3/)

Answer (score 0):

Personally I'd just resort to CSS for such a simple thing, not least because it is more like a visual thing than program logic:

```
<table class="table show-on-hover">
    <thead>...</thead>
    <tbody data-bind="foreach: Curriculums">
    <tr>
        <td data-bind="text: ID"></td>
        <td>
            <span data-bind="text: curCode"></span>
            <span class="shown-on-hover" data-bind="text: curDescription"></span>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody
```

CSS:

```
table.show-on-hover tr .shown-on-hover {
    visibility: hidden;
}

table.show-on-hover tr:hover .shown-on-hover {
    visibility: visible;
}
```

However, this is an alternative way, not really an explaination of *why* your solution does not work. The other answer posted here does a nice job at explaining that.